# Proftpd: difference between TimeoutNoTranfer and TimeoutIdle

Tags: ftp, timeout, proftpd

question:

What is the difference between these directive (Proftpd) ?

**TimeoutNoTransfer**
**TimeoutIdle**

From the proftpd documentation:

**TimeoutNoTransfer**: The TimeoutNoTransfer directive configures the maximum number of seconds a client is allowed to spend connected, after authentication, without issuing a command which results in creating an active or passive data connection

**TimeoutIdle**: The TimeoutIdle directive configures the maximum number of seconds that proftpd will allow clients to stay connected without receiving any data on either the control or data connection

I don't get the difference anyone could explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimeOutNoTransfer can only occur after login, as it states there.

TimeOutIdle will occur any time there is no traffic.

Comment: Oh ok, but how can a connection being established without login?

Comment: Where does it say anything about "no login" ?

Comment: Oh ok, I've understood now, these directive are pretty the same but the NoTransfer timer start once per session, the Idle timer can start anytime. Is it right?

Comment: Correct, but for completeness' sake, you can connect to an FTP server without logging in, of course - it's regular TCP.

Comment: Could you explain better this last comment? thanks :D you mean a user could start a synchronous connection with an ftp server without type the login?

Comment: FTP runs over TCP; a TCP session can be established, meaning the end-user connects successfully to the FTP server (and the FTP server will log this fact), but no FTP commands have been sent yet - including LOGIN.

Answer (score 0):

TimeOutIdle means that there is no activity at all. In this case it could happen between any 2 commands.
TimeOutNoTransfer means that there is no file transfer.

Comment: mmh this answer is not the same as adaptr told. You mean that TimeOutNoTrasfer timer could start anytime and not only after the login? Im pretty confused

Comment: This answer is not correct dude